# Time series Python ARIMA (testing,training and forecasting past dates available in data)

Tags: python, pandas, forecasting

I understand that separating data into training and testing provides a way to evaluate how well a model will perform with unseen data.

I am training an ARIMA model and I have daily data from Oct.1 to Nov.22. I am interested in predicting some metric on Dec.14. Do I

1. Train on all available data and use predict('2015-11-23','2015-12-14') or
2. Split data into train and test to get performance metrics and use the model trained on training set (oct.1. to Nov.7) and do a predict that includes the test data as well dates into the future, e.g. predict('2015-11-8','2015-12-14').

I hope my question makes sense, happy to clarify if you find this confusing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use all your data for training, then you will not have any way of predicting how well you model generalises to unseen data. That is one problem of not using a test set.

The other problem you will have, is that you will not be able to try different configurations or model hyperparameters unless you decide on some way of doing cross validation.

Data series prediction is specially tricky for cross validation, but I would follow [this post's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection) recommendation regarding forward chaining. If you have 6 weeks of data, you could split your data into folds as follows:

- fold 1 : training [w1], test [w2]
- fold 2 : training [w1 w2], test [w3]
- fold 3 : training [w1 w2 w3], test [w4]
- fold 4 : training [w1 w2 w3 w4], test [w5]
- fold 5 : training [w1 w2 w3 w4 w5], test [w6]